# Highlight points on an Excel Line Graph according to a list

Tags: excel

I have 2 data series, which records how much a user is meditating/attentive (out of 100) plotted onto a graph. The x axis is the number of seconds since the start of the experiment, and the y axis shows the value for meditation/attention at that point of time.

[image: The original data]
[image: The graph showing the change over time]

I have a 3rd set of data that is a series of key timestamps during the experiment (not exactly matching the timestamps from attention/meditation values).

[image: The important timestamps]

I want to create a graph where you can compare how the attention/meditation values change at the key points

[image: What I want my graph to look like]

Whether the key points are highlighted by a line or dots I don't care. I tried adding the 3rd data set as a secondary axis, but it still uses the original x-axis of the main graph and I don't know how to make excel do what I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may find this link helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/825692 You don't need to use the secondary axis, just add another series with tag times and constant 45 value, then format vertical error bars to 100% and horizontal to 0%.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You should submit this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an XY Scatter chart, not a line chart. A line chart ignores any numerical value in the X values, treats each X value as a text label, and uses the X values from the first series as X values for all series.

You can format the first two series so that they use lines and not markers, and the third so it uses markers without lines.

Comment: can you please explain steps to follow this bit detail? I am getting third also a line instead of only markers.

Comment: Select the series you want to format, press Ctrl+1 as a shortcut to open the Format Selected Item dialog or task pane, then format this series by keeping the markers but changing the line setting to No Line.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this link helpful: [superuser.com/questions/825692](https://superuser.com/questions/825692) You don't need to use the secondary axis, just add another series with tag times and constant 45 value, then format vertical error bars to 100% and horizontal to 0%.